# How can I add MP3 to the podcast app on my MacBook with Catalina 10.15?

Tags: iphone, itunes, catalina, podcasts, mp3

Before I updated to Catalina, I was able to add MP3 files to iTunes, then select get info -> options, and change media type to podcast. I was then able to listen to MP3s (which were mostly lectures) as podcasts on my phone, giving me the ability to rewind 15 seconds .

Now Catalina has disturbed my universe and removed podcasts from iTunes and isolated it as its own app. This no longer allows me to categorize songs as podcasts and I am therefore becoming stupider as the days go by.

How can I add MP3s to the podcast app on my MacBook Pro (Catalina 10.15)?

Comment: I've answered the question by the link, the only current way to listen to downloaded podcast files is via Books application. Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Yes, that is the solution I was looking for. Thanks!